# Is the likelihood with Poisson formula compatible with the likelihood expressed as product of likelihood parts?

Tags: likelihood

The likelihood of observing $n$ independent events while expecting $\nu$ events distributed according to the Poisson distribution is :

formula 1 : $L=e^{-\nu}\frac{\nu^n}{n!}$.

In addition, for independent events, the likelihood could be expressed as :

formula 2 : $L=\prod_i^n f(x_i)$

(for example :
https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/contents_sports.html
chapter statistics, formula 40.10)

where $f$ is the probability to *observe* $x_i$. (please note that the probability of not observing something does not enter in the formula : what enters is the probability of observing something).

My question is :
What is the expression for $f$ of (2) for the example of Poisson (1) that I gave ?

Indeed, I see no possibility of making a *product* of $f$ that would give the Poisson distribution.
(Indeed, the Poisson formula comes from the *sum* of Bernoulli formulas, not from a product. And Bernoulli formula comes from the *sum* of Binomial formula, not from the product.

So the trick of using $L=f^n*(1-f)^{\nu-n}$ times a combinatoric term, and going to the limit of high $n$, is not true, since in formula 2, only probabilities of *observing* an event enter : there are no probabilities of *not* observing an event that enter.

Could the formula 1 really obtained from formula 2 ?
If not, then the formula 2 is not "general" (not valid for all cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of a Poisson distribution looks a little over-condensed to me.

Meanwhile, your second expression applied to a binomial distribution would need to include not observing events that did not happen.  So if you want to treat a Poisson distribution as the limit of binomial distributions with constant expectation, you need to retain the binomial interpretation until you take the limit.

For fixed $n$ and $\nu$ you have $${m \choose n}\left(\frac{\nu}{m}\right)^n \left(1- \frac{\nu}{m}\right)^{m-n} \to e^{-\nu}\frac{\nu^n}{n!} \text{ as } m \to \infty . $$

Comment: Sorry, you seem to have the key explanation, but I miss something. For the formula 2 of product of likelihood of each events, why should we include the *events that we do not observe* ? I thought that we should include the probability of the events that we observe only ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian in a binomial event  of $n$ successes from $m$ attempts, the probability takes into account the $m-n$ unsuccessful attempts

Comment: thanks a lot for the help